# Formula Field Check Syntax not working

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to check the syntax of the following formula field but it is not displaying any information. When I try to save, it says there are error and to read the message below. When I scroll down there is still no error message.

I checked the parenthesis and everything seems fine. Does anyone know why this is not saving correctly? Or better yet, why the check syntax button is not working?

```
IF(((MONTH(MSA_Expiration_Date__c)+3)>12),

CASE(12-MONTH(MSA_Expiration_Date__c)+3, 
1, "January", 
2, "February", 
3, "March", 
4, "April", 
5, "May", 
6, "June", 
7, "July", 
8, "August", 
9, "September", 
10, "October", 
11, "November", 
12, "December", 
"None") + " " + TEXT(DAY(MSA_Expiration_Date__c))+", "+ TEXT(YEAR(MSA_Expiration_Date__c)+1), 

CASE(MONTH(MSA_Expiration_Date__c)+3, 
1, "January", 
2, "February", 
3, "March", 
4, "April", 
5, "May", 
6, "June", 
7, "July", 
8, "August", 
9, "September", 
10, "October", 
11, "November", 
12, "December", 
"None") + " " + TEXT(DAY(MSA_Expiration_Date__c))+", "+TEXT(YEAR(MSA_Expiration_Date__c)))
```

Comment: is `MSA_Expiration_Date__c` a formula field?

Comment: No, it is an editable date field.

Comment: What is the return type of the Formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Peter, this works for me in a formula returning Text. However, I think there's a logic error -- October dates for `MSA_Expiration_Date__c` return May, November returns April, and December returns March. You'd want to add 3 & subtract 12 (net, subtract 9) to get the month three ahead of the `MSA_Expiration_Date`'s. If that's what you want, the text representation of the date 3 months in the future, you can simplify this a great deal:

```
CASE(MONTH(ADDMONTHS(MSA_Expiration_Date__c,3)), 
1, "January", 
2, "February", 
3, "March", 
4, "April", 
5, "May", 
6, "June", 
7, "July", 
8, "August", 
9, "September", 
10, "October", 
11, "November", 
12, "December", 
"None") + 
" " + TEXT(DAY(ADDMONTHS(MSA_Expiration_Date__c,3))) 
+ ", " + TEXT(YEAR(ADDMONTHS(MSA_Expiration_Date__c,3)))
```

Using [`ADDMONTHS()`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5#ADDMONTHS) on the day as well as the month and year makes sure you're covering month-end scenarios and not returning things like `February 30, 2020` for an `MSA_Expiration_Date__c` of 2019-11-30.

Answer (score 2):

the code worked for me, Is the formula field set to text?

I tested the following with a standard field

```
IF(
    ((MONTH(LastActivityDate)+3)>12),
CASE(MONTH(LastActivityDate)+3, 
1, "January", 
2, "February", 
3, "March", 
4, "April", 
5, "May", 
6, "June", 
7, "July", 
8, "August", 
9, "September", 
10, "October", 
11, "November", 
12, "December", 
"None") + " " + TEXT(DAY(LastActivityDate))+", "+ TEXT(YEAR(LastActivityDate)+1), 
CASE(MONTH(LastActivityDate)+3, 
1, "January", 
2, "February", 
3, "March", 
4, "April", 
5, "May", 
6, "June", 
7, "July", 
8, "August", 
9, "September", 
10, "October", 
11, "November", 
12, "December", 
"None") + " " + TEXT(DAY(LastActivityDate))+", "+TEXT(YEAR(LastActivityDate)))
```